# Is this PHP crypt example correct?

Tags: php, encryption, hash, passwords, blowfish

To encrypt:

```
$encryptedPassword = crypt($password, '$2a$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$');
```

Should the **$usesomesillystringforsalt$** part be randomized or fixed? (I'm guessing fixed, but I want to be sure).

---

Result example:

```
$2a$07$usesomesillystringforeHwaCeDEv6rYjbWCzbzsFKwD4sDLktr
```

Is this a correct encrypted value?

---

To check if the given password by the user to log in is correct:

(Let's say there's an input field named `password` and compares it with the `$password` value retrieved from the database):

```
if (crypt($_POST['password'], '$2a$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$') === crypt($password, '$2a$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$')) {
    // Password submitted is correct
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? Then if it doesn't work as a specific question about it.

Comment: Well, it does apparently work. But maybe I'm missing something. I'm asking if there's something wrong with the logic behind

Comment: Are you storing the original or the encrypted password in the database? (it should be the encrypted one). In the 2nd block of code you posted, if `$password` is the value from your database, you don't need to crypt it again. You should compare `crypt($input,$salt) === $password`

Comment: Ah yes! I was re-encrypting the already encrypted saved password (I save the encrypted password, so that way not even I know the passwords) there.. Big mistake. Thanks for noticing

Comment: On a side note: You're hashing the password, not encrypting it. There's a very real difference there -- the latter is reversible, while the former (at least in design) is not.

Comment: Yes, but that's good in this case. I don't need the original password to compare it with what the user submits to log in. I just hash the input and then compare it with the value in the database.
I don't want anybody (not even me) to have access to the original value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically salts are stored in the database per-user, so if an attacker gets access to your entire password database, the attacker must brute-force each user individually.

Furthermore, it makes sense to use a per-site or per-application portion of the salt, to ensure that tables of common passwords and common salts (one or two characters would be easy, date would be tolerable, seconds since the epoch would be much larger, microseconds since the epoch would be difficult, 128 bits of randomness is impossible) can't be used against your application's database. If your per-user salts are large enough this is less useful -- so if your database has the space for storing larger per-user salts, go for it.

Comment: A salt per user + salt portion per table seems like A LOT. But it does ensure a lot more of security. I don't think, though, that brute-forcing a blowfish encrypted password is a simple job, but the more security the better